# Custom Alexa Skill Alexa thinks "this year" is "this week"

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I'm developing a skill for Alexa and the intent is like "How many times did this event happen {Timespan}." {Timespan} is an AMAZON.DATE slot. Acceptable utterances are "this week", "this month", and "this year". If I say to Alexa "How many times did this event happen this year" she interprets "this year" as "this week". If I say "How many times did this event happen", Alexa says "What time period do you want me to check?" If I say "this year" she interprets it as "this year". Any ideas about what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds very strange indeed. A workaround could be a custom slot-tpye, with values 'year', 'month' and 'week', as well as according synonyms, like 'this year'. Custom Slot Types tend to work better in my experience.